# React conditional rendered Form auto submits

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs

While developing an personal side project i've came across a notice i've not encountered before.

In the highest component there is a ternary, each containing a simple form:

```
{ this.state.isConnected
      ? <Chat handleSubmit={ this.handleChatSubmit } />
      : <Register handleSubmit={ this.handleRegisterSubmit } />
}
```

When the state changes (isConnected) it shows the Chat. The chat contains an form, so that the user can use the button and keys to submit their message. However, when i use the form element, it gives the next notice:
[Screenshot 1: Chrome debugger notice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34GfF.png).

Register.js

```
<form onSubmit={ () => this.props.handleSubmit(this.state) }>
      <label>
        <span>Username *</span>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="username"
          onChange={ this.handleChange }
        />
      </label>

      <button>Sign in</button>
    </form>
```

Chat.js

```
<form onSubmit={ () => this.props.handleSubmit(this.state) }>
      <label>
        <input
          type="text"
          onChange={ this.handleChange }
        />
      </label>

      <button>Send message</button>
    </form>
```

Each form is being prevented from submitting as followed:

```
handleSubmit = ({ message }) => {
...
this.socket.send(JSON.stringify(data))

event.preventDefault()
```

}

This issue is making the page reload and adds the message to the query parameters: `http://localhost:8080/?chat=it+is+refreshing`

If i use a different approach and stop using the form element, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you submit your form, you have to use e.preventDefault(), otherwise it will cause your page to reload when your form is submitted.

Change `onSubmit={ () => this.props.handleSubmit(this.state) }` to `onSubmit={ (e) => e.preventDefault();this.props.handleSubmit(this.state) }`

Or add a function that your form's onSubmit function calls like so:

```
handleSubmitForm = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.props.handleSubmit(this.state)
}
```

Comment: Hi MEnf, thanks for the comment. I am using the event.PreventDefault() in the callback handleSubmit. I'll update the question.

Comment: Hi MEnf, you're right. I understood that giving no parameter should give you access to the event itself, like suggested on https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html. I see now when you do provide a parameter it's a proxy?

Comment: I should probably have made my code a little bit clearer, the `e` in the parameter represents the element's event handler.  You need to access it from the function parameters to bind the proxy to the element it is being called from. https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html